# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

Tags: java, android

I am working on an app that contain drawer layout and navigation view in it.

When i try to launch app without NavigationView it works fine.

But when i include NavigationView to DrawerLayout it is throwing below error in logcat

[error showed in logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G40wV.png)

[java class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtVtb.png)

[layout xml image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCYZA.png)

[buil.gradle:app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cISyP.png)

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**FIRST YOU SHOULD DO THIS 
!! As you are going for a drawer layout why not to try a project with the built in boiler plate navigation drawer activity and compare the code with your project code?**

you are putting the navigation view above the menu bar! and add it below! first comment the code of navigation view and run the code! if it works fine then go for navigation view by putting it under the menu bar and try to use it again.

your styles.xml should look like this

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
          <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>

    </style>
```

for the app bar (aka tool bar)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:elevation="4dp">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: @SriDattaYalla what is your theme in app? check styles.xml please

Comment: are your design and app compact libraries of same version?

Comment: try to do some solutions referred here! like drawables moving etc 
https://github.com/Marketcloud/marketcloud-sample-android-application/issues/1

Comment: i have tried that before posting question, i didn't work

Comment: you are going for a drawer layout why not to try a project with the built in boiler plate navigation drawer activity and compare the code with your project code?